# Korean, Thai and Indonesian POS tagger

Tags: nlp, nltk, cjk, pos-tagger, thai

Can someone recommend an open source POS tagger for Korean, Indonesian, Thai and Vietnamese?

That I can use to tag the corpus data that I currently have. (e.g. [the stanford-postagger](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/index.shtml))

If you are a dev and care to share and let me test out the POS tagger, I don't mind either.

With some modifications of the output, I've POS tagged the Vietnamese data with [jvntextpro](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jvntextpro/)

But I'd still like more input on Korean, Indonesian and Thai POS tagging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After acl wiki: [Korean morphological analyzer and part-of-speech tagger](http://nlp.postech.ac.kr/DownLoad/k_api.html)

I would start to look on the websites of NLP research departments in Korea, Thailand, and Korean. [On this page](http://aclweb.org/aclwiki/index.php?title=Academic_departments#Thailand), you will find links to the research departments.

Good luck!

UPDATE: [OpenNLP](http://incubator.apache.org/opennlp/) has thai PoS. Here are the models: http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models/thai/  for PoS opennlp tagger.

Comment: http://isoft.postech.ac.kr/Course/CS730b/2005/index.html i've found the korean tagger on this page. now the thai tagger is missing. hahaa.. thanks for the page, but we need a better collation of NLP resources.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [RDRPOSTagger](http://rdrpostagger.sourceforge.net/): a robust, easy-to-use and language-independent toolkit for POS and morphological tagging.

(Programming language: Python & Java)

RDRPOSTagger obtains fast performance in both learning and tagging process. In addition, RDRPOSTagger achieves a very competitive accuracy in comparison to the state-of-the-art results. See experimental results including performance speed and tagging accuracy in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.4021).

RDRPOSTagger now supports pre-trained POS and morphological tagging models for 13 languages, including Thai and Vietnamese.